# Can't get ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in android

Tags: java, android

I want to get permissions for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in android but for whatever reason it only grants permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION .

My activity:

```
final int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        System.out.println("=========================================nottttt========================================================");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String PERMISSIONS[], int[] grantResults) {
    System.out.println("==================requesttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ALL: {
            System.out.println("lengthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"+PERMISSIONS.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < PERMISSIONS.length; i++) {
                String permission = PERMISSIONS[i];
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println(permission + "is alreadyyyyyyyyyyyyy grantedddddddddddddddd");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(permission + "is not grantedddddddddddddddd");

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}


public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String[] permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I start the app, I am prompted to give access to the location, I choose yes , but ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is not granted.Can somebody help me find the problem?

Comment: Without futher modifications, suddenly it says fine location granted which is ok.Does anybody know why this strange behaviour occured?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user granted permission to one of those permissions, the permission for the other will be granted too. You can't have one of them granted and the other not granted.

Comment: But why the print from onRequestPermissionResult finds ACCES_FINE_LOCATION permission as not granted.

Comment: Is it possible that it checks if it is granted before you grant it?

Comment: I think that is not the case, because I check the printings from the console after each touch of the screen, and it prints not granted ony after ii grant permission

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission allow app to use GPS and Network location providers. But, Network provider is a coarse location provider. That is why, if you request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION first, it will request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission authomatically